LWC WARNING: current engine is v7.1.3, but template was compiled with v7.1.4. Please update your compiled code
I found this error when I open a salesforce platform page with cutom LWC in it.
How can I fix this error?


I fixed this error by deleting the cache and restarting the browser.
--- Seq. 24, 2024 updated ---
Some of my colleagues never experienced this error.
Some of the others have encountered it but couldn’t fix it by simply clearing the cache and restarting the browser. The error just disappeared the next day.
It seems very random and confusing.
My final advice is to try using a different browser to see if that solves the problem.
--- Oct. 2, 2024 updated ---
I’ve realized that my answer does not solve the issue.
I apologize for the confusion.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

@TusharJadav I posted how I fixed the error which is exactaly what the question is asking for. Coud you give more info on this, so I can improve my answer? thanks.

I cleared the browser cache, restarted it, changed the LWC API version from 61 to 60, ran SFDX Update, but I still get this error.
